# How to extract a selected set of arguments of a variadic function and use them to call another function

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a variadic function *zoo* which takes N arguments, where N is known at compile time (it is a template parameter of the class containing the function).

```
template <int N>
struct B
{
    template <typename... Args>
    static void zoo(Args... args)
    {
        static_assert(size of...(args) == N, "");
       // do something
    }
};
```

I have another variadic function *foo* which takes M arguments, where M>N and is known at compile time (it is a template parameter of the class containing the function). I have a static index_array containing the indices of the arguments of *foo* I want to pass to *zoo*.

From the body of *foo* I want to call *zoo* passing a selected subset of the arguments of *foo*.

What is the best way to do this? Ideally achieving perfect inlining, i.e. so that everything is compiled into just one instruction with no function pointers indirections?

```
template<int...I>
struct indices
{
    static constexpr int N = sizeof...(I);
};

template <int M, typename...X>
struct A
{
    // here I am simplifying, in reality IS will be built at compile time based on X
    typedef indices<0,2,3> IS;

    template <typename... Args>
    static void foo(Args... args)
    {
        static_assert(size of...(args) == M, "");
       // do some magic to achieve the function call described in pseudo-code
       // B<IS::N>::zoo(args(IS(0),IS(1),IS(2)))
       // ideally this should be perfectly inlined to just have the call above
    }
};
```

Please note the code above is a simplification of my problem, designed for the purpose of illustrating the question.

EDIT:
As asked below, I describe the use case:
I am playing with a template based library to drive micro-controller pins. A micro controller has several ports (accessible as bytes in memory) and each port has up to 8 pins (bits). Class A is a bundle of pins via the template argument X, where every pin is defined as Pin. Class B manipulates all pins on the same port. A::foo is a function to modify some of the pins, with arguments in the same order as the order with which the pins are specified in the X template argument pack. foo needs to group the arguments by ports and dispatch to the B classes which representing individual ports, where all arguments are fused and written to the controller in a single instruction.

Comment: Could you describe a use case for this? Sounds like something that would be horrible to debug if it ever breaks. If the number of cases is foo/zoo pairs is less than about ten, I would just code them. Maybe pull them into `struct A` via CRTP.

Comment: Please see use case description added to the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a helper to extract the `nth_arg` like this:

```
template <int I>
struct ignore
{
  template <typename T>
  ignore(T&&) // This constructor accepts anything
  {
  }
};

template <typename T>
struct nth_arg;

template <size_t... DropIndexes>
struct nth_arg<std::integer_sequence<size_t, DropIndexes...>>
{
  template <typename Arg, typename... Rest>
  static decltype(auto) get(ignore<DropIndexes>..., // ignore args 0...n-1
                            Arg&& arg,
                            Rest&&...) // also ignore the rest
  {
    return std::forward<Arg>(arg); // return nth arg
  }
};
```

And then call

```
template <int... Is, typename... Args>
static void call_zoo(indices<Is...>, Args&&... args)
{
  B<sizeof...(Is)>::zoo(nth_arg<std::make_index_sequence<Is>>::get(
      std::forward<Args>(args)...)...);
}

template <int M>
struct A
{
  typedef indices<0, 2, 3> IS;

  template <typename... Args>
  static void foo(Args... args)
  {
    static_assert(sizeof...(args) == M, "");
    call_zoo(IS{}, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
};
```

If you're using C++11, you can easily roll your own `integer_sequence`.

Comment: Elegant solution, which does not requires tuples. +1

Comment: I wish the standard included some sugar syntax to access the nth_arg, which seems to me a common use case.

Comment: Rumburak: just to let you know I quoted your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34904049/how-to-create-a-sorted-mapping-integer-index-with-templates)

Comment: @Fabio :-) When you're done with those questions, I'd really like to know what you're up to. Looks like an interesting project. I'll look into that question tomorrow, I am too tired to grok it today...

Comment: Rumburak: That is all [here](https://bitbucket.org/fabiocannizzo/avr).  Please bear with me, as I just discovered C++11 two weeks ago. I wanted to use the two questions here to map _MultiPin::set\_values_ to _ByteBits::set\_values_. Eventually I simplified the implementation duplicating the code to build the mask and calling directly _ByteBits::set\_mask_.

Comment: @Fabio Thanks for the link! While I know nothing about programming micro-controllers, I like your aim of having the compiler detect as many errors as possible. Have fun with the project and with C++14 and beyond!

Answer (score 7):

Pack the arguments into a tuple of references, and then retrieve them with `std::get` and a pack expansion on the indices.

```
template<class Tuple, int... Is>
static void magic(Tuple&& args, indices<Is...>){
    B<IS::N>::zoo(std::get<Is>(std::forward<Tuple>(args))...);
}

template <typename... Args>
static void foo(Args... args)
{
    static_assert(sizeof...(args) == M, "");
    magic(std::forward_as_tuple(args...), IS{});
}
```

(You may want to make `foo` take forwarding references.)

Comment: This seems exactly what I need. I will give it a try. Thanks.