# How to create a sorted mapping integer index with templates

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, metaprogramming, c++14

I have the data structure:

```
template <int...I> struct index {};

template <typename...T> struct data {};

template <int I, int J> struct X
{
   static constexpr int i = I;
   static constexpr int j = J;
};

typedef data< X<0,4>, X<1,2>, X<2,1>, X<1,6>, X<1,3> > data_t;
```

Where *data* does not contain duplicates and the indices J are small, in the range 0-31.

I want to create a static index which contains the position in *data* of all X with index I equal to some given value (e.g. I=1), sorted by index J. It is the "sorting" bit which I find difficult.

For example, I would like to implement a class build_index such that:

```
typedef build_index<1,data>::type_t index_t;
```

generates the same as:

```
typedef index<1, 4, 3> index_t;
```

which reflects the positions in *data* of the elements X(1,J) ordered by J:
X(1,2) at data(1), X(1,3) at data(4), X(1,6) at data(3)

I would prefer not to use the STL, as it is not available for gcc-avr, although I could port selected snippets.

Comment: Are you allowed to change data?

Comment: Have you considered the Boost metaprogramming library (boost.mpl). See for example: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/sort.html You could roll your own sort, but it is easier to use one someone else has already written.

Comment: Your question is tagged with C++11. If you can use C++14, it would be a lot simpler.

Comment: @5gon12eder: I can use C++14

Comment: @simon: I do not understand the question. If you refer to <i>data</i>, yes, it is constructed based on other data, so it does change. I hard coded some values just for illustration.

Comment: @rici: yep, I know boost. Unfortunately there is no support for the stl in avr-gcc and boost relies on the stl, as far as I know. Plus it is quite a heavy dependency to have for such a small project as mine.

Comment: @Fabio: I meant wether there are some restrictions on which structures can be modified.

Comment: @fabio: afaik, boost.mpl has no such dependencies. It is header only and has been around for a long time.

Comment: @5gon12eder what non-standard-library C++14 feature are you thinking of that could help here?

Comment: @Fabio: boost libs often use the stl, but boost mpl mostly does not use the stl -- stl is not very useful for *metaprogramming* as it is mostly about providing data-structures for use at runtime. For instance compile time data structure cannot make heap allocations, and most STL data structures do that. If there is a "compile time" map in the mpl that fits your needs, you probably can use it without using the stl at all. If not, there certainly is one in boost hana which requires c++14

Comment: @fish2000 In C++14, you could simply store the information in a `constexpr` array and use ordinary C++ code for searching and sorting. Since the standard library has no relevant `constexpr` functions yet, you'll have to write them yourself which is why it still isn't a trivial task and which is why I didn't write an answer yet.

Comment: @5gon12eder that’s a great suggestion in general – even in non-embedded environments `constexpr` arrays are more legible and less awkward than using `std::index_sequence` and friends

Comment: @simon: You cannot change X and data. Worth nothing is that what I posted is a simplification, in my actual code I is not an int, but a type. Also I want obtain a structure which I can use at compile time as in rumburak's answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34836104/how-to-extract-a-selected-set-of-arguments-of-a-variadic-function-and-use-them-t)

Comment: @simon: however, we could change both I and J into integral_constant<>, if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are facing something complex in C++ template programming, it mostly helps to try to break it into several smaller steps (like with most programming problems). Here is a possible path:

1. Select the X which match the selected I and store them in a new data type replacing the I with the position (use recursion for this)
2. Sort the X in the selected_data by J. This is a bit annoying to write, I think. Maybe you should create a separate question for that.
3. Extract the positions from the sorted and selected X

And here is the corresponding code. I am using `std::conditional`, but that is easy to replace of course. I am using `std::is_same` in the tests, you do not really need that of course (and it would be trivial to implement otherwise).

Your stuff + utility header for std::conditional and std::is_same

```
#include <utility>

template <int... I>
struct index
{
};

template <typename... T>
struct data
{
};

template <int I, int J>
struct X
{
  static constexpr int i = I;
  static constexpr int j = J;
};

typedef data<X<0, 4>, X<1, 2>, X<2, 1>, X<1, 6>, X<1, 3>> data_t;
```

Extract the `X`s that match the `I` we are looking for and replace the `i`s with the position.

```
template <int Pos, int I, typename Extracted, typename Rest>
struct ExtractImpl;

template <int Pos, int I, typename... ExtractedX>
struct ExtractImpl<Pos, I, data<ExtractedX...>, data<>>
{
  using type = data<ExtractedX...>;
};

template <int Pos, int I, typename... ExtractedX, typename T, typename... Rest>
struct ExtractImpl<Pos, I, data<ExtractedX...>, data<T, Rest...>>
{
  using type = typename std::conditional<
      (T::i == I),
      typename ExtractImpl<Pos + 1,
                           I,
                           data<ExtractedX..., X<Pos, T::j>>,
                           data<Rest...>>::type,
      typename ExtractImpl<Pos + 1, I, data<ExtractedX...>, data<Rest...>>::
          type>::type;
};

template <int I, typename Data>
struct Extract
{
  using type = typename ExtractImpl<0, I, data<>, Data>::type;
};

using extracted = typename Extract<1, data_t>::type;
static_assert(std::is_same<extracted, data<X<1, 2>, X<3, 6>, X<4, 3>>>::value, "");
```

Sort by J. This is done by incrementally inserting elements into a sorted list. There might be more elegant ways to do it.

```
template <typename T, typename LessList, typename RestList>
struct insert_impl;

template <typename T, typename... Lesser>
struct insert_impl<T, data<Lesser...>, data<>>
{
  using type = data<Lesser..., T>;
};

template <typename T, typename... Lesser, typename Next, typename... Rest>
struct insert_impl<T, data<Lesser...>, data<Next, Rest...>>
{
  using type = typename std::conditional<
      (T::j < Next::j),
      data<Lesser..., T, Next, Rest...>,
      typename insert_impl<T, data<Lesser..., Next>, data<Rest...>>::type>::
      type;
};

template <typename T, typename SortedList>
struct insert
{
  using type = typename insert_impl<T, data<>, SortedList>::type;
};

template <typename SortedList, typename UnsortedList>
struct SortImpl;

template <typename SortedList>
struct SortImpl<SortedList, data<>>
{
  using type = SortedList;
};

template <typename SortedList, typename T, typename... UnsortedX>
struct SortImpl<SortedList, data<T, UnsortedX...>>
{
  using type = typename SortImpl<typename insert<T, SortedList>::type,
                                 data<UnsortedX...>>::type;
};

template <typename UnsortedList>
struct Sort
{
  using type = typename SortImpl<data<>, UnsortedList>::type;
};

using sorted = typename Sort<extracted>::type;
static_assert(std::is_same<sorted, data<X<1, 2>, X<4, 3>, X<3, 6>>>::value, "");
```

Finally, extract the indexes you are looking for:

```
template <typename List>
struct Indexes;

template <typename... Data>
struct Indexes<data<Data...>>
{
  using type = index<Data::i...>;
};

using result = typename Indexes<sorted>::type;
static_assert(std::is_same<result, index<1, 4, 3>>::value, "");
```

Word of warning: While I don't see any problems in the code, I have not tested it beyond your example...

Comment: Very nice! Thanks. +1

Comment: Glad you like it :-) BTW: When you think you got the answer you're looking for and don't expect something better to arrive soon, you should mark one answer as the correct one. Currently, all your questions are listed as unanswered.

Answer (score 2):

I'll share my approach to this problem which I think is kind of neat. I used C++11 `std::conditional`, and C++14 `std::integer_sequence` and `std::make_integer_sequence`, all of which you can find implementations of online.

Let's start with the data structures you had.

```
template <int... Is> struct index {};
template <typename... Ts> struct list {};
template <int L, int R> struct pair {};
```

We'll use a metafunction `concat`, which concatenates `N` list of types. We use it to filter a list by returning `list<T>` when the predicate returns `true`, and `list<>` otherwise.

For example, to filter the even numbers from `list<1, 3, 2, 4, 2>`, we can perform `std::conditional_t<I % 2 == 0, list<I>, list<>>` for each `I` to get `concat_t<list<>, list<>, list<2>, list<4>, list<2>>` = `list<2, 4, 2>`.

```
template <typename... Ts> struct concat;

template <> struct concat<> { using type = list<>; }

template <typename... Ts>
struct concat<list<Ts...>> { using type = list<Ts...>; };

template <typename... Ts, typename... Us>
struct concat<list<Ts...>, list<Us...>> { using type = list<Ts..., Us...>; };

template <typename... Ts, typename... Us, typename... Tail>
struct concat<list<Ts...>, list<Us...>, Tail...>
    : concat<list<Ts..., Us...>, Tail...> {};

template <typename... Ts>
using concat_t = typename concat<Ts...>::type;
```

Now we get to `build_index`. We perform bucket sort within the known range of `[0, 32)`. We could have used a generic sorting algorithm, but it was more fun to cheat.

```
template <int N, typename T> struct build_index;

// e.g., `build_index<
//            1, list<pair<0, 4>, pair<1, 2>, pair<2, 1>, pair<1, 6>, pair<1, 3>>`
template <int N, int... Ls, int... Rs>
struct build_index<N, list<pair<Ls, Rs>...>> {
  // Filter for pairs where `N == lhs`, and replace the `lhs` with the index.
  template <int... Is>
  static auto filter(std::integer_sequence<int, Is...>)
      -> concat_t<std::conditional_t<N == Ls, list<pair<Is, Rs>>, list<>>...>;

  // e.g., `list<pair<1, 2>, pair<3, 6>, pair<4, 3>>`
  using filtered =
      decltype(filter(std::make_integer_sequence<int, sizeof...(Ls)>{}));

  // `get<I>(set)` returns the `lhs` if `set` can implicitly convert to
  // `pair<lhs, I>` for some `lhs`, and nothing otherwise.
  template <typename... Ts> struct set : Ts... {};
  template <int I, int L> static list<index<L>> get(pair<L, I>);
  template <int I> static list<> get(...);

  // We invoke `get<I>` for `I` in `[0, 32)` to sort `filtered`.
  template <int... Is, typename... Ts>
  static auto sort(std::integer_sequence<int, Is...>, list<Ts...>)
      -> concat_t<decltype(get<Is>(set<Ts...>{}))...>;

  // e.g., `list<index<1>, index<4>, index<3>>`
  using sorted =
      decltype(sort(std::make_integer_sequence<int, 32>{}, filtered{}));

  // e.g., `list<1, 4, 3>`
  template <int... Is> static index<Is...> indices(list<index<Is>...>);
  using type = decltype(indices(sorted{}));
};

template <int N, typename... Ts>
using build_index_t = typename build_index<N, Ts...>::type;
```

With which we get:

```
using index_t = build_index_t<
    1, list<pair<0, 4>, pair<1, 2>, pair<2, 1>, pair<1, 6>, pair<1, 3>>>;
static_assert(std::is_same<index<1, 4, 3>, index_t>::value, "");
```